# adb -d forward tcp:5601 tcp:5601 fails to bundle AVDs of a phone and a wearable

Tags: android, adb, android-virtual-device, wear-os

I try to connect two AVDs. One ist a L-Preview Phone device and one is a wearable device.
I get twice the log message that no device was found.

```
➜  platform-tools  ./adb devices                     
List of devices attached 
emulator-5556   device
emulator-5554   device
```

If I check it with adb devices, two devices show up.

```
➜  platform-tools  ./adb -d forward tcp:5601 tcp:5601 # 5556 and 5554 won't work either.
error: device not found
error: device not found
```

Host OS: OSX Yosemite.

I search stackoverflow for the same question and I tried a lot of stuff but without understanding what's the problem, I cannot learn from my mistakes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flag -d is for USB-connected devices. Maybe you should try -e or better specify full device name. Start adb -help for more info.

Comment: Sorry I switch back to iOA development. If somebody is able to confirm this answer, please mark it! Thanks!